# How can I get the actual value of the char instead of the int value

Tags: objective-c, ios, char, int

So at first i was trying to use character at index, then convert it to nsnumber, and then get the int value, but for 9 i got a value of 57. So I knew what was going wrong, I'm getting the int of the character itself.

So I read a little, and found atoi, but I get this error, that doesnt crash my app jsut pauses it.

My code is:
     int current = atoi([startSquares characterAtIndex: i]);

Now startSquares is a big string full of numbers, and this above line is in a for loop where i goes from 0 to 99.

Comment: Just subtract the int value of char '0'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[57 is ASCII for the digit `'9'`](http://www.asciitable.com/). Assuming that by the "value of the char" you mean "the numeric value of the digit the char represents", you can use the simple trick available in ASCII:

```
int digit = char - '0';
```

This trick works, because all digits are encoded in order starting with the digit zero (ASCII code 48). So when you subtract `'0'` (which is another way to write 48) from 57, you get 9, the value of the digit `'9'`.

Comment: What I mean is that I want the value of current for the char '9' to be 9.

Comment: @PeterP This is your answer then :) You need to subtract 48, or `'0'`, which is the same thing.

Comment: ohhh, -'0' has value 48, ahhh i get what you guys mean now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad design, you should use an int array to hold your squares.

But if you absolutely insist on sticking with your approach, dasblinkenlight's way is the way to go. Just subtract the int value of char '0' from the char that you read.

Comment: The problem is this is like a level, so I get this complicated array of different numbers everytime, so I make a string and I want to "use" the value that is represented at each number to initalize this other array that I use for my game.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a character c '9' and you want the numeric value 9, you can use c - '0'.  It isn't clear that this is what you want, though.

If you have an array of char that contains a series of numbers (of more than one digit), you need to advance a pointer through that array, and then you could call atoi with that pointer, when it points at a digit (see isdigit), or you could use sscanf, or, you could put it in an NSString and get the next number using intValue.  But that would give you an NSInteger, not an NSNumber.  I don't think you really want an NSNumber, since you can't directly take the square of one.

Comment: These are all single digit numbers, and I am using atoi and it pauses the game.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it is obj c shortly after hitting <send> and edited the response.

Comment: Given that they are single digit (with no spaces) the c - '0' method should work fine.  If you have spaces you need to loop until isdigit(c) is true, and then you can use c-'0'.